# How can I exit the program from a sigTERM handler?

Tags: haskell

Consider something like this:

```
...

handleShutdown :: ThreadId -> IO ()
handleShutdown tid = doSomethingFunny >> throwTo tid ExitSuccess

main = do
    ...
    installHandler sigTERM (Catch $ myThreadId >>= handleShutdown) Nothing
    forever $ do
        stuff
    ...
```

If `sigINT` (Ctrl+C) is handled in this manner, the process finishes nicely. However, it seems like `sigTERM` is being used by Haskell internally and the code above doesn't exit from the main process at all. Is there a way to exit the process from a `sigTERM` handler without using an `MVar` and a custom loop? I couldn't find any information on the `sigTERM` handling anywhere (didn't read ghc sources, that's just too much for me to handle).

Update:

The following works:

```
main = do
    ...
    tid <- myThreadId -- This moved out of the Catch handler below.
    installHandler sigTERM (Catch $ handleShutdown tid) Nothing
    forever $ do
        stuff
    ...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry for short answer, but on mobile.

You want to run myThreadId from outside of the handler itself to get the main thread's ID. You're currently getting the ID of the signal handler itself.

Comment: Well, that was easy:) I feel a bit stupid now. You're right, that seems to work well. Thank you!

Comment: Sure, no problem, really easy mistake to make. Second set of eyes can catch such things much more easily :)